# Batch File to Add Multiple Values if Condition True

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd, registry

I want to query registry for a value, if the value exists I want to modify it, if it doesn't exist I want to go to the next similar key and check.

Key:

> ```
> HKCU\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\001
> HKCU\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\002
> HKCU\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\003
> ```

The value is the same for each key but I need to cycle through each one to check until I have checked all of them.

What I am currently doing is:

```
reg query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\001" /v MyValue
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
     reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\001" /v MyValue /f /t REG_DWORD /d 10
) else (
     goto :KEY2
)
```

This will cycle through all the keys I need to check and modify each but it is quit a few lines and I am thinking perhaps I could build a subroutine of some type to accomplish this but I am kinda stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code queries the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MySoftware` for all immediate sub-keys, filters for those whose names consist of three decimal figures, loops through them in ascending order, queries the value `MyValue` for each and if found, modifies the respective data:

```cmd
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%K in ('
    reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MySoftware" /K /F * ^
        ^| findstr "^HKEY_.*\\[0-9][0-9][0-9]$" ^| sort
') do (
    reg query "%%K" /V "MyValue" && reg add "%%K" /V "MyValue" /f /t REG_DWORD /d 10
)
```

The used `&&` operator lets the following command execute only if the preceding one succeeded.

Comment: Both answers from yourself and @Magoo work very well however I selected this answer as the best answer as it allows me to run this on more than 3 if I need to without having to define them all.

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%a in (001 002 003) do (
 reg query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\%%a" /v MyValue
 if not errorlevel 1 (
  reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\MySoftware\%%a" /v MyValue /f /t REG_DWORD /d 10
 )
)
```

should accomplish this. `errorlevel` is interpreted in its conventional manner on its run-time value. All you need do is modify the list in parentheses, each value of which is assigned in turn to the `metavariable` `%%a`